# logstash send log file to redis

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I need to send my access log file to redis through logstash. My logstash is under /usr/share/logstash and the configure file is under /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf

test.conf:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/data/service_logs/services/semapi.access.log"]
    type => "syslog"
  }
}


output {
  redis{
   host=>'127.0.0.1'
   port=>6379
   key=>'access'
   data_type=>'list'
}
```

}

i run it with :

```
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/redis.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash
```

The logstash log:

```
Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

and there is no error shows up. but i did not get the value for the access list.

I tried to send simple string to redis through logstash, it works well. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try run this command:

```
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf
```